# How to match a php string value?

Tags: php, if-statement

1st check out the code:

```
$smsbonus = "Rs. 0.00";
$pattern = "/class=\"monthes_sub_heading\">(.*?)</i";
preg_match_all($pattern, $ha, $matches);

for ($x = 0; $x < count($matches[1]); $x++) {
    if ($matches[1][$x] == date("Y-m-d")) {
        if ($matches[1][$x + 1] == "By Sending Sms")
            $smsbonus = $matches[1][$x + 2];
    }
}

if ($smsbonus = Rs.2) {
    echo "Rs. 2 Match Found";
} else {
    echo "Not Found.";
}
```

But it's not working properly.

What I wanted was to detect if:

```
$smsbouns = Rs. 2
```

If so, then echo that the match was found.

But when I run it, when my `$smsbouns` is not `Rs. 2`, it's still echoing that the match was found. :\

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Or could someone give me a correct version?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youre not testing against a string . Put "Rs. 2" in quotes:

```
if($smsbonus == "Rs. 2")
```

Also you're using a single equal sign, which assigns it to RS. 2, and doesn't check against it. You have to use "=="

Comment: Ohhh.
Thanks. Now Its Working Fine... :)

One Little More help please.


if i want use OR then its ok ??


if($smsbonus == "Rs. 2" || $smsbonus == "Rs. 1.98")

Comment: Also remember the issues in php with "==" vs "===" - something else to watch out for!

Comment: Yes, the || is fine, just remember that it will work for either condition.

Answer (score 1):

one `=` is actually **setting** the value; therefore it will always be true.

you want `==` which tests **if** it is true

or `===` which tests if it is true **and** the type is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Will never work with what you trying, = is assigning operator you have to use == operator for comparison. do this

```
if($smsbonus == "Rs. 2")
```